# Specify the length of an edge

Tags: node-editor

I want to create an equilateral triangle.

I added a plan and then merged the two points on one edge .. that seemed to work fine.

The length of the bottom of the triangle is 2m and I'd like to set the length of the other edges to 2m.

Is there an easy way to set the length of an edge?

I understand that I can do some math and figure out the x,y for the top and move that point to create the correct length, but I'd like to just set the length of an edge if possible.

[image]

Comment: The easiest way is to use the *Extra Objects* add-on (*Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*) to create an equilateral triangle (*Add > Mesh > Math Function > Triangle* and adjust the type to *Equilateral* in the *Adjust Last Operation* panel in the lower left corner of the 3D View).

Comment: Thank you this was perfect. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to comments, to create an equilateral triangle, side length `L` -

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> call up a Circle
- In the fields of the *Adjust Last Operation panel*, type into *Sides*: `3`,  and *Radius*: `L*sqrt(3)/3`

Comment: argh... math... ; )

Comment: @lemon Zackerly.  I'd use yours, any day. Your comment gave me permission :)

Comment: ... so have added another way as adding another way yourself gave me the permission : )

Comment: Your turn, to add another one... challenge!!

Comment: Thank you, this was also a quick and easy option.

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be simple to set the pivot point as 3D cursor, place it on a corner of a 2x2 meters plane and activate X symmetry:

[image]

The rotation in this case is 30 degrees.

Remove doubled vertices after that.

Note: specifying the length of an edge won't solve the case or we'd need to set the length of the 2 edges simultaneously. And as far as I know this does not exist in Blender.

**Another way** can be starting from one single edge of two meters and spin it -60 (remove doubles after that):

[image]

**And another way** Start with a 2 meters edge. Subdivide. Move the center sqrt(3), select all and make a face:

[image]

Comment: Neat. You can also get it to snap.

Comment: @RobinBetts, yes or grab sqrt(3) along Y from the middle of the base.

Comment: These all look like great options. To be honest though I'm so new to the software that I'm getting a little lost trying to follow these instructions. Rather than waste your time with a bunch of silly questions, I'll go do some homework and then come back to these ones .. thank you though :)

Comment: Had to be AFK.. but still, I can't come up with anything snappier than your first method....